# Elasticsearch how to delete data without id from an index?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is an item have no id, any way to delete it unless using `_delete_by_query`?

the one I wanna delete like this:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 230,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "info",
        "_type": "default",
        "_id": "",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "city_id": 1,
        }
      },
```

I tried python by:

```
query ={
   "query":{
     "match":{
       "city_id":1
     }
    }
}
es.delete_by_query(index,type,query)
```

And doesn't work, the bad data still in the index.
`{u'_type': u'default', u'created': False, u'_shards': {u'successful': 2, u'failed': 0, u'total': 2}, u'_version': 8, u'_index': u'info', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query'}`

Comment: So you don't have an id - but what do you have to identify a document?

Comment: This is a bad item, I need to delete it.

Comment: I don't get it. You need to now anything about that document, otherwise how can you adress that specific document? Maybe you could provide us with some more information on that question.

Comment: Edited. Elasticsearch didn't generated an id for that item.

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch is that?

Comment: "lucene_version": "5.5.0", "number": "2.3.5"

Answer (score 2):

An elasticsearch document has always an `_id` field. It can be automatically generated by Elasticsearch or provided by you.

So the first thing to do is to find your document, with a `_search` call. Then extract the `_id` and run:

```
DELETE INDEX/_doc/ID
```

Which is basically what the delete by query is doing behind the scene.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't generated _id.

Comment: It always generate _id for each document and probably you set as null by "POST /info/_doc/  " which in this case you ignored auto generation of _id and set it as "" by this api call.

Comment: Yes, but I wanna delete the empty _id document.

Comment: Could you create a query which is a bool / must_not / and a regexp query which can select your document?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that elastic search always generates an [_id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html) for all indexed documents and probably in indexing stage you set it as null, Either way you can simply use the [delete_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) Api and delete your document with following script

```html
POST /info/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "city_id": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran this on sense of es, looks like this not be supported....

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query. You have set _id as an empty string, which seems valid. Hence delete using id where-in id is "".

```
DELETE <indexName>/_doc/""
```

I tried reproducing locally and it worked for me.

Comment: This will delete one which id ="\"\"", the empty id still here.

Comment: You tried it out ? I am able to remove doc with empty id using the same